# Generate a list of contacts from a table based on a Bool value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am currently developing an asp.NET MVC web application as a front end to a database. I have a MySQL database, one of the tables is contact information for employees. I have added a column of 'isOnSite' of datatype TINYINT(1).

I have updated the data model in my application, and added a checkbox control for this in one of my view. This works fine, I edit a contact, check the box to say that they are currently contracted to this particular site, and a '1' is populated in the 'isOnSite' column for that particular record, great!

One of the views is a Dashboard. In this view (using a partial view) I would like to generate a list of the contacts in the table that have the value of 'isOnSite = true'

I am struggling to do this. I should mention that I am pretty new to all of this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Thank you in advance!

### --                                       EDIT                                 --

With the help of @Bunnynut and also my Father-in-Law We managed to solve this,
in large part to the code examples by @Bunnynut.

CONTROLLER ACTION

```
        public ViewResult Index()
    {
    var tblcontacts = from m in db.tblcontacts.Where(x => x.isOnSite)
                          select m;

        return View(tblcontacts.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ToList());
    }
```

PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<ResourceBase.Models.tblcontact>

 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "OnSite";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

  <h2>OnSite</h2>

<div class="container-fluid-viewport jumbotron col-xs-offset-4">

     @foreach (var x in Model)
     {
          @x.FullName  <br />
     }

</div>
```

And the Main view just renders the partial view.

Thanks again for your help @Bunnynut

Comment: Maybe you should try to solve the problem, and if it does not work, then update the post

Comment: @ArthurSwails Tinyint is essentially a boolean in MySQL.

Comment: @efekctive Thanks for the advice. But I've been at this all day and I am still coming up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with the Index View uses a model of type ResourceBase.Models.tlbcontact which is it seems a single tblcontcat.
But you are try to pass a List to your partial view so that is not possible.

You Index View should consume a model of which it pass parts of it to your partial views.

IndexViewModel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<ResourceBase.Models.tblcontact> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Index Action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = 
        new IndexViewModel
        {
            Title = "PeopleBase Dashboard",
            Employees = GetEmployees()
        };
    return View(model);
}
```

Index View:

```
@model IndexViewModel
<div class="container-fluid-viewport col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<div class="partialViewWrapper jumbotron">@{Html.RenderPartial("_peopleBaseDashView", Model.Employees.Where(x =>   x.isOnSite).ToList());}
</div>
</div>
```

Your partial View looks ok to me

Comment: Getting very close. Sorry you must be getting frustrated by now.
    Employees = GetEmployees()
The Name 'GetEmployees' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I've been playing around with it for the past hour and Can't figure it out.
I've added:

private List<tblcontact> GetEmployees()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

After it and it breaks when trying to run it with a NullReferenceException

Comment: No problem at all!
GetEmployees() is the function you still have to implement to get the Employees from the database.

Comment: Would that be in the Model for tblcontact? IE: public string GetEmployees { get; set; }

Comment: Do you already have a function that executes a query on your database to retrieves the employees? GetEmployees() would be that function.
In my comment Employees = GetEmployees() you can replace the GetEmployees() part with a call to that function in your code.

Comment: Ah. No I don't, I'm using Enitiy Framework connected to MySQL database.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Entity Framework but GetEmployees() would look something like this
`code`
public List<tblcontact> GetEmployees()
{
    return DbContext.Set<tblcontact>().ToList();    
}
`code`

You have to set DbContext.

Comment: Right! After another day of messing around with it I've finally cracked it.
I use the term 'I've' very loosely... 90% of it was with your help @Bunnynut
I also enlisted the help of my father-in-law
I will Edit my post to show how I(we) solved it. Again, without your solution(s) it wouldn't be working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `SELECT` statement

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE isOnSite = 1
```

to fill a property of your ViewModel, which you can then display in your view.

Comment: Just a note: Never actually use `*` as your `SELECT` clause in a query that will go to prod, type out the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass the list of employees directly to your partial view as long as you tell your partial view the model passed is of that type.
So in the master view containing the code that call the partial view you can do this:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("NAME_PARTIAL_VIEW", employees.Where(x => x.isOnSite).ToList());}
```

And in you partial view:

```
@model List<Employee>
@foreach(var employee in Model)
{
    @employee.Name
}
```

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing I am after.
The Index view is as follows.

@model IEnumerable<ResourceBase.Models.tblcontact>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PeopleBase";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="container-fluid-viewport col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
    <h2>PeopleBase Dashboard</h2>
   
    <div class="partialViewWrapper jumbotron">@Html.RenderPartial("_peopleBaseDashView", .Where(x => x.isOnSite).ToList());
    </div>
</div>

Comment: I am getting stuck at before the '.Where(x => x.isOnSite)'

Comment: Not sure what to pass here

Comment: The .Where(x => x.isOnSite) is a lambda expression which let you do a query on a collection like an array or a list. If your list already contains the data you need you can leave that part out.
What is the reason you are stuck on that line?

Comment: I'm not sure of what needs to be in front of '.Where'

Comment: employees is in this case a variable containing a list of employees.
You need to make sure your master view consumes a model that contains a list of employees, so that way you can pass the employees to your partial view: Model.employees.Where(x => x.isOnSite).ToList()

Comment: Ok i've managed to sort that out, thank you very much for you help. 
Another issue is now i'm getting " 'char' does not contain a definition for 'isOnSite' "

Comment: Please post some of your code, that will make it a lot easier to answer your question

Comment: To begin with the Index View uses a model of type ResourceBase.Models.tlbcontact which is it seems a single tblcontcat.
But you are try to pass a List<ResourceBase.Models.tlbcontact> to your partial view so that is not possible.

You Index View should consume a model of which it pass parts of it to your partial views.

IndexViewModel: